# how can I change my call condition into a switch case

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to change this condition into a switch case according to this condition I set API  call will work if this condition will match.

```
useEffect(() => {
        user?.app_permission == true &&
        user?.corp_permission == true &&
        appName == "@common/su"
          ? (fetchAppList({
              id: data.search_id,
              ...(appName !== "@common/su" ? parameter : {}),
            }),
            fetchCorpList({
              id: data.search_id,
              ...(appName !== "@common/su" ? parameter : {}),
            }))
          : user?.App_permission == true &&
            user?.corp_permission == false &&
            appName == "@common/su"
          ? fetchAppList({
              id: data.search_id,
              ...(appName !== "@common/su" ? parameter : {}),
            })
          : user?.corp_permission == true &&
            user?.App_permission == false &&
            appName == "@common/su"
          ? fetchCorpList({
              id: data.search_id,
              ...(appName !== "@common/su" ? parameter : {}),
            })
          : null;
    }
```

Comment: it will be tough as switch have only one para

Comment: oh ok that I implement that is complex I am thinking switch case will make it easy that i am assuming @AshishKamble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function demo(appName, user) {
    let conditionOne = user ? .app_permission == true && user ? .corp_permission == true && appName == "@common/su";
    let conditionTwo = user ? .App_permission == true && user ? .corp_permission == false && appName == "@common/su";
    let conditionThree = user ? .corp_permission == true && user ? .App_permission == false && appName == "@common/su";

if (conditionOne) {
    let fetchAppList = fetchAppList({
            id: data.search_id,
            ...(appName !== "@common/su" ? parameter : {}),
        });
      let fetchCorpList = fetchCorpList({
            id: data.search_id,
            ...(appName !== "@common/su" ? parameter : {}),
        });
    return [fetchCorpList,fetchAppList];
}
if (conditionTwo) {
      let fetchAppList = fetchAppList({
            id: data.search_id,
            ...(appName !== "@common/su" ? parameter : {}),
        });
    return [fetchAppList];
}
if (conditionThree) {
    let fetchCorpList = fetchCorpList({
            id: data.search_id,
            ...(appName !== "@common/su" ? parameter : {}),
        });
    return [fetchCorpList];
  }
return null;
}


useEffect(() => {
     let result = demo(appName,user);
  },[])
```

Comment: what is result[0]();
            result[1](); ??

Comment: but result[0](); is not function why need () this

Comment: @devdeveloper my mistake, I have updated the answer.